# Azure Logic Apps FTP concurrent triggers

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am working on a Azure Logic app that reads added files from an FTP and sends them as POST to an Azure function. After this the file is removed from the FTP server.
The total execution time is about 1 second.
The problem that i am facing is that the Logic app only seems to process one file at a time, because of this the logic app can only handle max 60 new files a minute.
I have set the concurrent runs to 42, but this does not seem to change anything.

How can i make this Logic app process these files quicker?

```
  "triggers": {
            "When_a_file_is_added_or_modified": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['ftp']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/datasets/default/triggers/onupdatedfile",
                    "queries": {
                        "folderId": "L2Z0cC9maWxlcw==",
                        "includeFileContent": true
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "L2Z0cC9maWxlcw==": "/ftp/files"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Second",
                    "interval": 15
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "concurrency": {
                        "runs": 42
                    }
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the FTP connector problem, you could check the trigger [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/ftpconnector/#when-a-file-is-added-or-modified), it never say it could response multiple files.

If you modify multiple files same time, it will trigger the logic app multiple times. And if [concurrent setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#concurrency-looping-and-debatching-limits) is off it means unlimited, also no max 60 files limit.

I test with 100 files, it all could trigger. The result will be like the below picture, they will run at the same time.

[image]

Comment: @Marknl, if this could help you, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the behavior of the FTP trigger is that it only returns one file at a time (especially in this case when file content is included in the body of the trigger), but gets a signal if more files ready to be triggered and will immediately fetch the next.  Whether it will go fetch the next is where your concurrency setting is helpful. So behavior:

1. At polling interval, check for new files
2. If a new file, trigger.  Trigger will also include a “is there more” or “is that all?” Flag (the `retry-after` header)
3. If there is more, *immediately* go back and fetch next file.
4. If there is not more, wait for next polling interval
5. Repeat

Comment: I do not understand. Where is this retry-after header and "is there more" infirmation coming from?

Comment: The connector sets it for you. It’s part of the connector code to set that header if there are more than one files that have been uploaded